# Capybara run with Firefox 52 - unable to connect to Mozilla geckodriver

Tags: ruby, firefox, selenium-webdriver, capybara, geckodriver

When running Ruby UI tests with Capybara I am getting Error:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: unable to connect to Mozilla geckodriver 127.0.0.1:4444
        /home/hudson/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:130:in `connect_until_stable'
        /home/hudson/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:74:in `block in start'
        /home/hudson/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_lock.rb:41:in `locked'
        /home/hudson/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:71:in `start'
        /home/hudson/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/w3c_bridge.rb:41:in `initialize'
        /home/hudson/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:52:in `new'
        /home/hudson/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:52:in `for'
        /home/hudson/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:88:in `for'
        /home/hudson/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:23:in `browser'
        /home/hudson/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:49:in `visit'
        /home/hudson/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:274:in `visit'
        /home/hudson/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:50:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
        /home/hudson/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/site_prism-2.11/lib/site_prism/page.rb:36:in `load'
```

Version that I am using:

```
Ruby: 2.4.0
Firefox: 52.6.0(This is required for my tests)
Geckodriver: v0.17.0
capybara: 2.18.0
selenium-webdriver: 3.4.0
```

Driver is set by this code:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :firefox)
end
```

When I run the same tests on Chrome or latest Firefox(with Geckodriver v0.20.0) everything works great. But I need to run these tests of Firefox 52. I have tried different combinations between Geckodriver and Selenium-webdriver but unsuccessfully so far.
I have used https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/tree/v0.17.0 documentation.

Comment: Each version of geckodriver only supports a few versions of Firefox. Since Firefox 52 was released Mar 7, 2017 - and geckodriver 0.15 was released Mar 8, 2017 - I would expect those two to be compatible, but 0.17 may be too new.  Note that geckodriver back that early in 2017 had a number of bugs and missing features so trying to test with it may not be worth your time.